# Too many git push to remote git origin - high cpu - process hung

Tags: git, performance, github, networking, large-data

I have Git repo which is pretty large, more than 50GB. There is this shell script which manipulates files in this Git repo and makes lots of commits and pushes them to remote git repo(github).

There are two parts here, file manipulation and pushing the files to git repo. No issues with file manipulation, git push is having issues.

There is a text file which contains all the files which needs to be committed. And the shell scripts loops through the text file and for each file it executes git add, git commit and git push.

I see the script is executing for more than 4 hours and it stuck leaving high cpu and memory usage.

git push is http based and not ssh based.

Checked linux processes and found lots of git push process, one of them looks like below,

- git push - parent process
- git-remote-http child process
- git send-pack
- git-pack-objects child process

git-remote-http using 80-90% cpu and git-pack-objects using 15-20% cpu.

Tried using strace on git push process and found lots and lots of select calls, only select calls.

```
select(6, [5], [5], [], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=50000}) = 2 (in [5], out [5], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=49999})
select(6, [5], [5], [], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=50000}) = 2 (in [5], out [5], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=49999})
select(6, [5], [5], [], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=50000}) = 2 (in [5], out [5], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=49999})
select(6, [5], [5], [], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=50000}) = 2 (in [5], out [5], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=49999})
```

Tried using strace on git-pack-objects process, output looked like below, nothing else.

```
write(1, ...)
```

Tried running,

```
pgrep -f 'git.*pack-objects' | xargs -r ps -o pid,%cpu,time,etime,%mem,s,args | cat
```

And I see git-pack-objects is running for 4 hours but cpu time used is only around 45 minutes.

Script is running on 4 core machine and 1 core is 100% utilized not all 4.

I believe some git config tweaking will help in resolving this issue.

Comment: The pack-objects code is very CPU- and memory-intensive. That's a separate program; the main Git front end process is just waiting for it to finish. If you don't have enough physical RAM, you'll be doing a lot of paging. You can configure Git not to try to compress large files, though usually the defaults are pretty good for this.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Using Git 2.30..